# integral of a product of functions

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f$ be a continuous function at the interval $[a,b]$ such that for every function $g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we get $\int_{a}^{b}(f(x)\cdot g(x))dx =0$. Does it necessarily mean that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$?

I think it's not true, but I'm really not sure. I don't know that many interesting functions relating to integrals to give an example. The Riemann function isn't 0, but I don't know if for every function we'll get $\int_{a}^{b}(f(x)\cdot g(x))dx =0$.

Comment: Take $g(x):=f(x)$. Then $f$ must be zero almost everywhere.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm sorry, I don't understand your answer. Where are we asked to define g(x)? The statement says "for every function g:[a,b]".

Comment: If it is true for any function, it must be true for $f$, as $f$ is a function. This is enough for a proof.

Comment: @YvesDaoust In fact $f=0$ everywhere.

Comment: @zhw: of course, as $f$ is continuous. I was only giving half of the solution...

Answer (score 1):

If there exists an $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)\neq 0$, w.l.o.g. we can assume $f(x_0)>0$. Then by the continuity of $f$, one has an inteval $[c, d]\subset [a, b]$, $(c<d)$ small enough such that $f(x)>0$ on $[c, d]$ and denote $\alpha =\min_{x\in [c, d]}f(x)>0$. Take $g(x)=0$ if $x\notin [c, d]$ and $g(x)=1$ if $x\in [c,d]$. Then
$$0=\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx=\int_c^d f(x)dx\geqslant \alpha(d-c)>0,$$
this is a contradiction. Hence $f=0$ on $[a, b]$.

Comment: Thanks - How can you prove that if the function is continuous, and there's $x_0$ s.t $f(x_0) > 0$, then there's an interval $\delta > 0$,  $[x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta]$ s.t $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta]$?

nevermind, just remembered the IVF. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The easiest way is to draw a graph and zoom in the behavior of $f$ at $x_0$ :). Actually $f(x_0)$ does not need to be positive, but if $f(x_0)<0$ we also have a similar argument.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f\neq 0$, i.e. $\exists x^{\prime}\in (a,b)$ such that $f(x^{\prime})\neq 0$; let's say $f(x^{\prime})>0$. Then by continuity there is an open interval $(x^{\prime}-\epsilon,x^{\prime}+\epsilon)$ around $x^{\prime}$ such that $f(y)>0$ for $y\in (x^{\prime}-\epsilon,x^{\prime}+\epsilon)$. Let $g$ be the characteristic function $\chi_{[x^{\prime}-\frac{\epsilon}{2},x^{\prime}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}]}$, i.e.
$$g(x)=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  1 \text{ if } x\in [x^{\prime}-\frac{\epsilon}{2},x^{\prime}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}]\\
                  0 \text{ else}
                \end{array}
              \right.$$
then by the mean value theorem $\exists y^{\prime}\in [x^{\prime}-\frac{\epsilon}{2},x^{\prime}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}]$ such that 
$$\int_a^b f(x)g(x) = \int_{x-\frac{\epsilon}{2}}^{x+\frac{\epsilon}{2}}f(x)dx = f(y^{\prime})\cdot \epsilon >0.$$

Therefore $f$ must be $0$. Note however if $f$ is not continuous than $f$ does not have to be $0$. For example $f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ with
$$f(x)=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  1 \text{ if } x=0\\
                  0 \text{ else}
                \end{array}
              \right.$$